Milliseconds not set when reading date-time field from Access database using FireDAC
Delphi app, Access database: migrating from ADO to FireDAC
I’m in the process of migrating my Delphi 12 VCL windows application from MS Access database to PostgreSQL  .
My first step is to migrate the provider from ADO to FireDAC.
My problem is that when reading a date-time field from the database using FireDAC the milliseconds are not preserved.
Reading the same field with ADO might produce
24-12-2024 12:00:00:123
while with FireDAC I get
24-12-2024 12:00:00:000
The issue is the same regardless of the latter field is configured as a DateTime or SQLTimeStamp.

Are you using the datetime extended datatype? If not, the fact that you can reliably store millisecond time in an ordinary datetime field is really a hack, and you should expect trouble when touching it because different systems will handle this hack differently.

@ErikA I dont use the date/time extended type. I haven't experienced any problems reading/writing millesecs using ADO. I hope to find equivalent methods using FireDAC.

Well, tough luck.  You can verify these milliseconds aren't actually visible in Access nor are they exported using the tools built into Access. It only worked because ADO uses the same underlying data structure for datetime fields. FireDac doesn't as far as I know. You likely need to change the data structure to a field that supports milliseconds without hackery.

This is probably a limitation of FireDAC (which I know nothing about), as DateTime in Access can perfectly well handle milliseconds, though not supported natively neither in VBA nor the user interface of Access. See my library (module DateMsec.bas) on GitHub: VBA.Date

If you read "can perfectly well" as "can store reliably and do arithmetic with" then you're right. But that's a small part of the use cases. For most other uses (display, manipulate, export, etc.) it's not supported. This is more an anomaly that ADO and DAO do support it, than a limitation of FireDac, since it's not documented and officially supported functionality. You can hardly blame a program for not behaving identically in undocumented use cases.

@ErikA Can I enable the extended date/time data type i my customers databases programatically fra my Delphi application? Adox? I can't seem to enable it in my Access installation even though I (my company) use Office version 2212 (15928.20282).

@JacobHavkrog You're using an .accdb file right? Then it should be under File -> Options -> Current Database at the very bottom. You should be able to use it programatically as far as I know, but note that everyone accessing it (even through ADO) will need to use a recent version of Access or the Access Database Engine.

@ErikA I use a .mdb file. Converting it to .accdb opens up for the option to change to the extended date/time data type. Thanks. But converting my 300 customers databases from 2000 to current format , and then changing the date/time data type is not feasable I think. Some might not have Access installed, or an old version of Access. I guess I need to use a double precision float field to store my datetime values. Not ideal since it will be more cumbersome for me to inspect the values in Access during development and debugging.

Yup, that's unfortunate, mdb files do not support date-time extended. I'd probably do the same. You can take inspiration from the functions shared by Gustav for working with millisecond times in floats, since they essentially treat datetime fields as floats. If you keep the same 0-time as Access, you can also easily convert back and forth with CDate and CDbl on the Access side to minimize the inconvenience.
